# Delta merge using InsertAll() / UpdateAll() and EXCEPT keyword

Tags: pyspark, databricks, delta-lake

I want to use Merge operation on two Delta tables, but I don't want to write complex Insert / Update conditions, so ideally I'd like to use InsertAll() and UpdateAll(). It works well, but my source table contains an extra column that I don't want to populate to the target data, but I can't drop it as I need it to identify records to be deleted.

I found in documentation that there is an EXCEPT keyword that I could use. There is a sample written in SQL:

```
MERGE INTO target t
USING source s
ON t.id = s.id
WHEN MATCHED
  THEN UPDATE SET last_updated = current_date()
WHEN NOT MATCHED
  THEN INSERT * EXCEPT (last_updated)
```

Is there any way I could use the same in PySpark?

I know that I could write custom Insert and Update conditions, but that causes problems with Schema Evolution that don't happen when using InsertAll / UpdateAll()

Comment: Could you also give a working example where you use the insertAll() and updateAll()? Although it adds a column? I am very interested in that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no such functionality in the PySpark yet. But it's really to implement it programmatically, something like this:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

update_df_name = "updates"
excluded_columsn = ["col1", "col2"]
values_to_insert = dict([(cl, col(f"{update_df_name}.{cl}")) 
  for cl in df.columns if cl not in excluded_columnes])

deltaTable.alias("events").merge(
    source = updatesDF.alias(update_df_name),
    condition = expr("events.eventId = updates.eventId")
  ).whenNotMatchedInsert(
     values = values_to_insert
  ).execute()
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I'm using similar code right now, but the main problem I face is that with this approach I can't benefit from automatic schema evolution.

Comment: I think that it should be a feature request on Delta Lake repository...